# How to treat missing values in a regression?

Tags: econometrics, missing-data, logarithm

I have used the logarithmic form of wage as my independent variable in Stata. However, it contains missing values. Should I replace these with 0 or let them be?

Comment: How many variables your full dataset has? Multiple imputation would be the proper way to handle missing values. However, if you have just two variables (in the _full_ dataset, not just this particular analysis), there might not be much that can be done.

Comment: There are a total of 8 variables. The data is missing for wage=0 as taking its logarithmic form produces missing values

Comment: Oh, that's a different thing. Missing values refer to no observation at all. You could for example set the wages that are less than one (the point after $log x$ becomes negative) to zero.

Comment: But log(wage) provides a missing value for wage=0. My question is: should I let the missing values be, when using log(wage) as an independent variable for multiple regression?

Comment: First calculate the logarithm for those wages that are larger than or equal to one. Then set the remaining was to zero.

Comment: The right way to handle your situation is to look at log(wage+1). Then the argument for log will never be zero or negative (assuming there is no such thing as a negative wage).

Comment: @user93729 The point that mmh made is really important.  This kind of phenomena, when a transformation is applied outside of it's domain, is **not** what is generally meant by the phrase *missing values*.  It may be true that a specific software platform uses the same mechanism to represent both situations, but still, they are quite different.  You should always be as clear as possible when communicating these things.

Comment: You should ask yourselff whether attempting to use a single model for this is appropriate.  Do you suspect that the forces causing or influencing wage=0 are the same that affect the magnitude of the wage given that it is non-zero?